# Providing checkboxSelectMultiple with values

Tags: python, django

Problem is that I can't populate my checkboxSelectMultiple widget with choice values that have been selected and forwarded through instance in the view.

These are the relevant classes:

View:

```
if sid and request.method != "POST":
    try:
        obj = Service.objects.get(pk=int(sid), user=request.user.pk)
        form = addNewService(instance=obj)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Form:

```
class addNewService(forms.ModelForm):
    pk = forms.HiddenInput()
    authorities = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=authorities.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True)
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    #organisation_logo = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        #exclude = ("user",)
        fields = (  'service_name',
                    'category',
                    'service_duration',
                    'price',
                    'bursarie',
                    'vat_included',
                    'travelExpensesIncluded',
                    'authorities',
                    'type_of_delivery',
                    'description',
                    'active',
                    )
```

Model:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    authorities = models.ManyToManyField(authorities)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def removeServiceURL(self):
        return "/Services/Remove/%s"%self.pk

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s @ %s"%(self.service_name, self.user.username)
```

Checkboxes display accordingly, but when I open the form from an instance, everything fills up correctly except the checkboxes, which are all unchecked.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I guess you only need to change the widget for the field? If so, you can use `widgets` [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets) without redefining the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def your_view(request, sid=None):
    if sid and request.method == "GET":
        try:
            obj = Service.objects.get(pk=sid, user=request.user)
            form = addNewService(instance=obj)
        except Service.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

#rest of view
```

You don't want to swallow all of the exceptions in your try/except. Check for the specific exception(s) you're handling; it makes debugging a lot easier. Also, in your queryset, you were trying to match the user on the primary key, but comparing it to the object: user. If you wanted to match on the pk, do: `user__id=request.user.id` however, this will fail if the user is anonymous.

Comment: Taken everything into consideration, and implemented your advices in the rest of my code, but the checkboxes still are not checked :(